# XSL-FO – footnotes in lists

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

In my stylesheets, I use templates for three levels of nested lists:

```
● level 1
  ▲ level 2
    ○ level 3
```

It is quite common to use footnote inside of the list. The problem is, such footnotes in some way inherit the list’s indentation:

[image]

I have tried almost everything, from using `start-indent` for the footnote to treating whitespace inside the list. Nothing helps. Is there any specific attribute I could use for ignoring the parent’s indentation?

The code for the `footnote-body`:

```
<fo:footnote-body>
  <fo:block font-family="{$serif}" font-size="11pt" line-height="1.5" text-align="left" margin-left="0pt" text-indent="7pt">
    <fo:inline font-size="70%" baseline-shift="super" color="red">
      <xsl:call-template name="calculateFootnoteNumber"/>
    </fo:inline>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="footPars"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:footnote-body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, obviously:

```
<fo:footnote-body>
            <fo:block font-family="{$serif}" font-size="11pt" line-height="1.5" text-align="left" margin-left="0pt" text-indent="0">
                <fo:inline font-size="70%" baseline-shift="super" color="red">
                    <xsl:call-template name="calculateFootnoteNumber"/>
                </fo:inline>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="footPars"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:footnote-body>
```

The couplet of `margin-left="0pt"` and `text-indent="0"` did the right thing! Before the `text-indent` was `7pt`. Setting it to `0` helped.